# Expired mongo data with TTL index and data restores

Tags: mongodb, indexing, ttl

I am busy considering using a TTL index on a collection in MongoDB and wondering what the effect would be in the event of a restore.

For example, if I set the TTL on a collection to 2 days:

```
db.logEvents.ensureIndex({"datestamp":1},{expireAfterSeconds:172800})
```

If I were to back up the daily using mongodump restore a week later, would the logEvents collection be empty? For mongodump / mongorestore, I was considering modifying / removing the index manually in `logEvents.metadata.json` before restoring - would this work?

What about if restoring from raw data files - how can I start up the mongod service with restored raw files in the datadir without immediately expiring data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a nice problem!

To check that I created a collection and tested your scenario, where restored data is outside of the ttl.

The records were restored and in next few seconds removed from collection.

After changing index details in **metadatafile** I was able to list records outside original ttl window.

removed entry:

> ,"expireAfterSeconds":36.0

Restoring from raw files could also have a play as long as you are using `NMAP` engine. 
`WiredTiger` stores some extra data outside files and I was unable to restore collection from WT file.

Have a fun!

Comment: Thanks Prof, marking your answer as the correct seeing as though you tested and confirmed the approach worked.

Comment: @Brett it is my pleasure :-)